# Install ImageMagick cli from repository

Tags: package-management, 19.04, imagemagick

I want to use imagemagick to automate some image conversions. Unfortunately, when installed by building the source it misses the codec for opening `png` images. As far as I can tell, the fix for this is installing imagemagick 'properly' from a repository through `apt` [source](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/675). The issue is, however, when I run `sudo apt install imagemagick`, apt says that it is already installed (even though I don't have the `magick` or any other commands)

Error message from the magick command when opening a png file (command from manually made/installed magick):

```
magick: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/556.
```

Comment: Can you give some background on why you installed from source, when it comes baked into Ubuntu? Might help understand the situation you are in.

Comment: As stated, while apt said it was installed it doesn't look like I have access to the actual commands (`magick`, etc)

Comment: Why did you install it from source?

Comment: because there were alot of guides online saying that was how install it. and unsure of what else to doif apt said it was installed but couldn't actually use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, turns out that while the `magick` command is not available, the other commands are; `convert`, etc.

I used `man imagemagick` to find this out.

So...

Instead of: `magick pic.png pic.tiff`

Use: `convert pic.png pic.tiff`

Leaving this q/a here for posterity because I can't be the only one confused by the lack of the `magick` command.

Comment: You're a hero mate. I was going insane over this. Thanks for posting your solution.